# Meteor publication.ready returning false

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to use Meteor's pubsub pattern but my publication is returning `false` on `ready()`. This seems to be a bit of an anomaly, there aren't many issues of this kind on the internet - which probably means I'm missing something basic, anyway here we go:

```
// in /app/server/collections/clubs.js
import ClubSchema from '../schemas/clubs.js';

export const Clubs = ( function() {              // <- tried refactoring to 
    var clubs = new Mongo.Collection('clubs');   //    standard collection declaration
    clubs.attachSchema(ClubSchema);
    return clubs;
} )();
```

---

```
// in /app/server/publications/clubs.js
import { Clubs } from '/app/server/collections/clubs.js';

Meteor.publish('clubs', function () {
  console.log("hello, world!");
  return Clubs.find();
});
```

---

```
// in /app/client/templates/new-club.js
Template.App_clubs.onCreated(function () {
    Meteor.subscribe('clubs');
});
```

Comment: What happens if you autorun your sub? Like `this.autorun(function(){ var sub = Meteor.subscribe('clubs');console.log(sub.ready());});`

Comment: `false` then `true` :O

Comment: This is what is called reactivity. The autorun is some kind of binding itself to reactive data sources (and a subscription is such) and then always re-run when the data source changes. Nice to know: In Java this is known as observer pattern.

Comment: understood - so when the reactive data source, i.e. the publication, changes the autorun is re-fired... It also runs as soon as the page is run (hence the `false`) but why then does it become `true`? There isn't anything mutating the data source?

Comment: In this the client has successfully loaded all documents, that were published, so that the underlying "ready" state is changed. The source's state is not limited to the documents but also the state of the subscription.

Comment: I think I got it from here - thank you so much for that, would've taken me ages to get to the bottom of that :)